# Using choice with 2 fields of the same name in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Can i somehow make choices based on content of the field? For example if answer is yes, there would be 2 additional fields - Color and Size.
This example gives me error, because of 2 same fields - "answer". For me only way to fix that is to place "answer" in the end of the sequence, but i need to have the same order of fields.

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Answer" fixed="N" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Answer" fixed="Y" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Color" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Size" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
```

Comment: Similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250731/distincting-xschoices-in-xsd-by-using-fixed-values-for-element-with-enumeration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One solution:  replace `<Answer>Y</Answer>` and `<Answer>N</Answer>` with `<Yes/>` and `<No/>`.  Now the content model for the parent is

   ```
   <xsd:choice>
     <xsd:element name="No" type="my:empty"/>
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="Yes" type="my:empty"/>
       <xsd:element name="Color" type="xsd:string"/>
       <xsd:element name="Size" type="xsd:string"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:choice>
   ```
2. A variation on this would be to make Color and Size be children of Yes, not siblings.
3. A third option would be to eliminate the Answer element entirely.  It's completely redundant, since either you have Color and Size (and the Answer is Y) or you have neither Color nor Size (and the Answer is N).  Your problem is that you are having trouble enforcing the consistency of Answer with the other information present; in almost any IT application the easiest way to reduce problems of consistency enforcement is to reduce redundancy.  Why include things which convey no actual information and whose only function is to make your life harder?
4. If the software you're using to read the XML is not intelligent enough to handle this, then a fourth option is to make Answer an attribute on the parent, instead of a child element, then use XSD 1.1 and conditional type assignment to select a type for the parent based on the value of the Answer attribute.
5. A fifth option is to use XSD 1.1 and assertions to enforce the consistency rules necessary to protect the redundancy in your design.

Of these, those with the best XML skills are (in my experience) likely to recommend the second or third; those with the least often seem to like the fifth.